# Primeira aba do ion-tabs não mostra os dados

Tags: ionic, typescript

Tenho o seguinte template com duas abas

```
  <ion-tabs  tabsPlacement="top" color="primary" #entradaSaidaTabs >
    <ion-tab [root]="tabReceber"  [rootParams]="paramsChart" tabTitle="Entrada"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab [root]="tabPagar" [rootParams]="paramsChart" tabTitle="Saída"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

A variável passada via **rootParams**, `paramsChart`, recebe os dados de uma api por meio da função `carregaMovimentacoes()`.

```
paramsChart: any;

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.carregaMovimentacoes();
}
```

Quando a página está ativa, somente a segunda aba mostra a lista com os dados, a primeira permanece em branco. O estranho é que ambas recebem a mesma variável via **rootParams**, porém na primeira aba ela é `undefined`, enquanto na segunda, ela possui a lista com os dados.

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.paramsChart = this.navParams.data; // Recebe o os parametros da pagina raiz
  }
```

Como exibir a lista com os dados também na primeira aba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após obter os dados via API, passe eles para a aba via `publish()`

```
this.events.publish("paramsChart:changed", paramsChart);
```

Na primeira aba, se inscreva, e espere a resposta do evento

```
 this.events.subscribe("paramsChart:changed",(res) => {
    this.paramsChart = res;
 });
```